# what happens at Java interpreter level when IncompatibleClassChangeError is thrown?

Tags: java, exceptions, interpreters, jvm

I am  a noob at JVM internals.

Can someone explain what happens at Java interpreter level when IncompatibleClassChangeError is thrown?

I am facing an issue similar to the one described here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4171827 but having a hard time understanding this comment(quoted from the same page):

> This is actually a bug in the interpreter's handling of IncompatibleClassChangeError. The bug is that the logic that checks for invoking a method on a null object, which results in a NullPointerException, is executed before the logic that checks for IncompatibleClassChangeError. In the case of a non-static method becoming static this will cause the interpreter to read a value of the stack which isn't guaranteed to be valid. In this test case it reads a value one above the top of stack which may or may not have a valid value in it. If you modify the test slightly to push a couple nulls and then pop them off before doing the invocation, the test will fail on every vm JavaSoft has shipped. Here's the modified test...

Comment: Keep in mind that is bug is *ancient*, it was fixed in 2002. Current JVMs most likely work quite different.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt It ll still help if I can understand that. I am working with v1.5 - might not be all that different.

Comment: It can have many different reasons, explained in detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html).

Comment: Yes but I still couldnt understand this line: " In the case of a non-static method becoming static this will cause the interpreter to read a value of the stack which isn't guaranteed to be valid."

Answer (score 1):

I may say that the issue isn't fixed but is closed as non-reproducible.

> Yes but I still couldnt understand this line: " In the case of a non-static method becoming static this will cause the interpreter to read a value of the stack which isn't guaranteed to be valid."

Most likely the point is that in the case of **static** method top cell of the stack is **ignored** when the method is invoked and may contain `null` (or undefined value). In the case of **non-static** method the top cell contains `this` reference.

> Can someone explain what happens at Java interpreter level when IncompatibleClassChangeError is thrown?

I'd refer you to the [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)